# php-mysql: different access page during login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, accessibility

I have confused for this login method, especially for different access page for some users after login.

I have some user list in my DB like:

1. admin
2. user

I want if I'm login as `admin` will direct to `input.php` and if I login as `user` will direct to `index.php`. i have read from some sites that it must use switch-case. But, I'm still unclear how to use that.

```
$dbc=mysql_connect(_SRV,_ACCID,_PWD) or die(_ERROR15.": ".mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db("qdbase",$dbc) or die(_ERROR17.": ".mysql_error());

switch(postVar('action')) {
        case 'submitlogin':
                submitlogin(postVar('loguser'),postVar('logpass'));
                mysql_close($dbc);
                exit;
                break;
}

function submitlogin($loguser,$logpass){
        if(isset($loguser,$logpass)){
                $myuser= mysql_real_escape_string($loguser);
                $mypass= mysql_real_escape_string($logpass);
                $sql= sprintf("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user = '".$myuser."' AND password = '".$mypass."'", $myuser,$mypass);
                $result = mysql_result($sql) or die (_ERROR26.": ".mysql_error());
                if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                        session_register("loguser");
                        session_register("logpass");

      switch $myuser{                          //i dont know its correct or not
           case 'admin':
               header("location:input.php");
               break;
           case 'user':
               header("location:index.php");
               break;
           }    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
        <META http-equiv='refresh' content='2; url=index.php'>
</head>
<title>Login success</title>
<body>
        <h1>You logged in !</h1>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }else
        {
            header("location:log.php?msg=" . urlencode("Wrong Username or Password. Please retry"));
       }
    }else{
       header("location:log.php?msg=" . urlencode("Please enter some username and password"));
    }
}
?>
```

i got this error:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_result() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/jeinqa/www/oqc/dolog.php on line 29 // on line 17 in this page
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($loguser));` stripslashes is not needed here, and should be omitted.

Comment: Storing passwords in the clear in a database is a cardinal sin. Use salted hashes with SHA2 instead.

Comment: @Johan: ok, i already delete it. But how about the switch case in my script? how should i do to make my login page have different access for each user?

Comment: If you have only one login screen for both users and admins, you need to check the email exists in both user and admin table. If you found the user in admin, redirect the user to respective page else to other page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is to redirect user 'admin' to other after-login page, instead of

```
header("location:index1.php");    //i want to use switch-case in this part
```

you need something like

```
switch($loguser) {
    case "admin" :
         header("location:input.php"); 
         break;
    default: // this branch will run for all users other than 'admin' 
         header("location:index.php"); 

}
```

Comment: I have tried this but `admin` still direct to index.php. why?

Comment: @nunu then make sure that $loguser is actually "admin".

Comment: change `mysql_result` to `mysql_query`